# Getting grepl to return TRUE only if there is a match with the full string

Tags: r, grepl

I have example data as follows:

```
library(data.table)
dat <- fread("q1   q2 ...1  ..2  q3..1 ..1
       NA   response other  else response other
       1    4        NA   NA   1    NA")
```

I wanted to filter out all columns that are automatically named when reading in an Excel file with missing column names, which have names like `..x`. I thought that the following piece of code would work:

```
grepl("\\.+", names(dat))
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

But it also filters out columns which have a similar structure as column `q3..1`.

Although I do not know why the `..x` part is added to such a column (because it was not empty), I would like to adapt the `grepl` code, so that the outcome is `TRUE`, unless the structure is ONLY `..x`.

How should I do this?

Desired output:

```
grepl("\\.+", names(dat))
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE TRUE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an anchor `^` to state that the dots have to be in the start of the string:

```r
grepl("^\\.+", names(dat))
#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

We may do

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
   select(matches('^[^.]+$'))
      q1       q2
   <int>   <char>
1:    NA response
2:     1        4
```